# How to turn off optimistic concurrency check in SqlCe, linq-to-sql (SqlMetal)?

Tags: sql, database, linq-to-sql, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

Using: VS2008, Sql CE 3.5.

When I try to save an entity from a detached context, i'm not able to. And instead have to map each property.

```
    Public Sub Save(ByVal user As Users)
    Dim ctx As New TestDB(connection)

        Dim q = (From n In ctx.Users Where user.Id = id Select n).Single
        q.MapData(user)
        ' ctx.Users.Attach(user, q)             ' Does not work
        ' ctx.Users.Attach(user, True)          ' Does not work
    End If
    ctx.SubmitChanges()
```

It's indicated that turning off optimistic concurrency check will avoid this problem. (As answer here: [Entity attachment issues in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536400/entity-attachment-issues-in-linq)).

But how do I turn that off? Do I manually have to edit the SqlMetal-generated datacontext classes in some way? Or can it be done simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I added this attribute to all properties in the entity classes. Not sure if that's the best way though.

```
UpdateCheck:=UpdateCheck.Never
```